# How to update a managed metadata file property in SharePoint Online

Tags: powershell, metadata, taxonomy, sharepoint-online

I am trying to set a property value on a Managed Metadata column on files in a folder located in a document library.  I can set values for other metadata as they are text fields.  I believe I have to cast it to another type in order to set the value.  I have tried various methods I found but nothing seems to work.  "Doc Type" is the managed metadata column in question.

```
$files = Get-PnPFolderItem -FolderSiteRelativeUrl $folderRelativeUrl -ItemType File 

foreach($file in $files)
{
    write-output $file.Name
    $file.Properties['Business Unit'] = $Global:BusinessUnit
    $file.Properties['Customer Name'] = $Global:CustomerName
    $file.Properties['Customer No'] = $Global:CustomerNumber
    #$file.Properties['Doc Type'] = $Global:DocType
    $file.Properties['Doc Type'] = $term.Name
    $file.Properties['Job Name'] = $Global:JobName
    $file.Properties['Job Number'] = $Global:JobNumber
    $file.Properties['Opportunity Name'] = $Global:OpportunityName
    $file.Properties['Opportunity No'] = $Global:OpportunityNumber
    $file.Properties['Quote Name'] = $Global:QuoteName
    $file.Properties['Quote ID'] = $Global:QuoteNumber
    $file.Properties['System'] = $Global:System
    $file.Update()
```

I am using this command to get the term from the term store

```
$term = Get-PnpTerm -TermGroup "Document Types" -TermSet Document -Identity $Folder -ErrorAction Ignore
```

$Folder is the name I am looking for in the term store, eg: "Quote".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider the following options to set taxonomy value:

> Note: it is assumed `Doc Type` is a *single valued* taxonomy field

**Option 1**

Via [`Taxonomy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.taxonomy.aspx) from CSOM API as demonstrated below:

```
$files = Get-PnPFolderItem -FolderSiteRelativeUrl $folderRelativeUrl -ItemType File 

$term = Get-PnpTerm -TermGroup $termGroup -TermSet $termSet -Identity $termId 

#1. get taxonomy specific field
$ctx = $files.Context
$field = $files.ListItemAllFields.ParentList.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle($fieldName) 
$ctx.Load($field)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
$taxField = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext].GetMethod("CastTo").MakeGenericMethod([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField]).Invoke($ctx, $field)

foreach($file in $files)
{
    write-output $file.Name

    $taxField.SetFieldValueByTerm($file.ListItemAllFields,$term,1033) #2.update taxonomy field value
    $file.ListItemAllFields['Job Name'] = $Global:JobName
    $file.ListItemAllFields.Update()
    #$file.Update()    
}
```

**Option 2**

Via PnP-PowerShell [`SetPnPTaxonomyFieldValue` cmdlet](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/blob/2.12.1702.0/Documentation/SetPnPTaxonomyFieldValue.md):

```
foreach($file in $files)
{
    write-output $file.Name
    Set-PnPTaxonomyFieldValue -ListItem $file.ListItemAllFields -InternalFieldName 'DocType' -TermId $term.Id        
}
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that is was a single value.  Option 2 works fine.  Thanks for the response.